# Активировать буттон при выборе всех чекбоксов

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Есть несколько чекбоксов. Как активировать буттон submit только если выбраны все чекбоксы?

Comment: Ответ кроется в самом вопросе.  Повесить обработчик на изменение чекбоксов. Внутри написать код: если все чекбоксы чекнуты - активировать кнопку, если нет - задисейблить

Comment: Вот вам материал для изучения, по нему сможете написать решение: [*input* event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event), [Spread syntax (...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), [`every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Как активировать буттон submit только если выбраны все чекбоксы?

Как вариант, можно такое сделать вот так.

```js
const of = document.querySelector('form')
const all = of.querySelectorAll('[type="checkbox"]').length
of.addEventListener('click', _ => {
  const o = of.querySelector('button')
  o.disabled = of.querySelectorAll(':checked').length != all
})
```

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <input type='checkbox' />
    <input type='checkbox' />
    <input type='checkbox' />
    <input type='checkbox' />
  </div>
  <button disabled>Тест</button>
</form>
```